# Returns an array of all inputs with specified name

Tags: javascript, array, form, dom

I've made a nice little function to return a `NodeList` array containing all the inputs that have a specified name attribute:

```js
function GiveElementsByName(name) {
var finalOutput = [], times = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length, inOutput = 0, inAll = 0; //For use later.
while(times--)
{
if (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[inAll].name == name) //Apply to all inputs with specified name.
 {
 finalOutput[inOutput] = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[inAll]; //Array with all the matching inputs.
 inOutput++;
 }
inAll++;
}
return finalOutput;
}
function MyFunc() {
  GiveElementsByName("Lol1")[1].value = "I don't like potatos anymore";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Lol1" value="I like potatos">
<input type="text" name="Lol1" value="I like potatos">
<input type="text" name="Lol1" value="I like potatos">
<input type="text" name="Lol1" value="I like potatos">
<br><br><br><br>
<input type="text" name="Lol2" value="I like potatos more">
<input type="text" name="Lol2" value="I like potatos more">
<input type="text" name="Lol2" value="I like potatos more">
<input type="text" name="Lol2" value="I like potatos more">
<br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onClick="MyFunc()">
```

Could you help me shrink down the function and make it quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Naming:** `Give…` is unconventional; usually we say `get…`.  The function only looks at `<input>` elements, so that should be part of the name.  The "final" in `finalOutput` doesn't contribute to the clarity.
- **Performance:** You're calling `document.getElementsByTagName()` many times.  That DOM access is probably the most expensive call in your code, so you should do it just once and remember its result.
- **Initialization:** This is one long line with poor readability:

  > ```
  > var finalOutput = [], times = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length, inOutput = 0, inAll = 0; //For use later.
  > ```

  Eliminate as many variables as you can, and break up the rest into multiple lines of code.
- **Looping:** A common idiom for a loop that runs *n* times is

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      …
  }
  ```

  There are times when `while (times--) { … }` is appropriate, but this is not one of them, since you need an `inAll` that counts up anyway.
- **Building the array:** If you use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), then you don't have to keep track of `inOutput`.

```
function getInputElementsByName(name) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name == name) {
            out.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: OK. gonna implement one by one. How do i look at all the tags instead of inputs only? would "*" work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/1157100

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2694640/1157100

Comment: Not sure if you will see this, but I'm very sorry for delaying working on this thing for such a long time. You might have forgotten me :D. So my question is, how do I correctly update my code? I mean i could answer my question but that would make others unable to answer...

Comment: See http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763

Answer (score 2):

The `GiveElementsByName` function is poorly indented.
And the variable declarations should not be only a single extremely long `var` line,
but each variable should be on its own line.
It's better like this:

```
function GiveElementsByName(name) {
    var finalOutput = [],
        times = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length,
        inOutput = 0,
        inAll = 0;
    while (times--) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[inAll].name == name) {
            finalOutput[inOutput] = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[inAll]; 
            inOutput++;
        }
        inAll++;
    }
    return finalOutput;
}
```

It seems to me that there is an easier way to do this using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), which should be supported by modern browsers:

```
function GiveElementsByName(name) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('input[name=' + name + ']');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The big thing would be to call `getElementsByTagName` no more than you need to. In your method, you call it once to get the length, then twice more for every result (once to get the name, then again to add it to your array). This could require the code to parse the DOM an excessive number of times.

In the example code below, I call `document.getElementsByTagName` only once.

```
function GiveElementsByName(name) {
    var finalOutput = [], tags = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), inOutput = 0, inAll = 0, times = tags.length; //For use later.
    while(times--){
        if (tags[inAll].name == name){ //Apply to all inputs with specified name.
            finalOutput[inOutput] = tags[inAll]; //Array with all the matching inputs.
            inOutput++;
        }
        inAll++;
    }
    return finalOutput;
}
```

However, since you're really looking for two different properties of the elements (the tag name "input" as well as the name attribute) you could try using `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByTagName`, which allows you to specify a complex CSS selector.

At a glance, your function could thus be replaced with:

```
function GiveElementsByName(name) {
    return document.querySelectorAll("input[name="+name+"]");
}
```

Comment: Ermmm... Hmm... *Realizes he's stupid*... Well, **I choose the fancy way!**

Comment: Not stupid, just taking a different approach. In fact, depending on the browser and the element(s) being selected, getElementsByTagName can be faster than querySelectorAll. Check out [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/id-and-css-selectors/2) for some comparisons.